# is invoking a service into another service in angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to save data and then I need to dispaly the changes immediately afterwards.
That's why I Have a

- updateSaisine which allows me to update data
- getOneSaisine which allows me get the data and display them:

Which is the more correct way and for which reasons ?

Should I write:

```
$scope.saveSaisine = function() {
   saisineSrv.updateSaisine($scope.currentSaisine.idSaisine, $scope.currentSaisine).
   then(
       function() {
           $scope.errorMessages = [];

              if ($scope.currentSaisine.idMotif) {
                 toaster.pop('success', 'Réponse', 'Success');
                 angular.element('#modalSaisine').modal('hide');

                 saisineSrv.getOneSaisine($scope.currentSaisine.idSaisine, $scope.currentSaisine).then(function(response) {
                     $scope.currentSaisine.dateModif = response.dateModif;
                 });

         },
         function error(response) {
             $scope.errorMessages = response.data;
             toaster.pop('error', 'Réponse', 'We have a problem');
         }
    );
};
```

OR

```
$scope.saveSaisine = function() {
   saisineSrv.updateSaisine($scope.currentSaisine.idSaisine, $scope.currentSaisine).
   then(
       function() {
           $scope.errorMessages = [];

              if ($scope.currentSaisine.idMotif) {
                 toaster.pop('success', 'Réponse', 'Success');
                 angular.element('#modalSaisine').modal('hide');

         },
         function error(response) {
             $scope.errorMessages = response.data;
             toaster.pop('error', 'Réponse', 'We have a problem');
         }
    );

   saisineSrv.getOneSaisine($scope.currentSaisine.idSaisine, $scope.currentSaisine).then(function(response) {
       $scope.currentSaisine.dateModif = response.dateModif;
   });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first option is a correct way how you should refresh your data because these services are asynchronous thus in the second example you may don't get fresh data (the getOneSaisine can finish before updateSaisine).